# Missing value after join two query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, null, join

I have query:

```
select 
       coalesce(t1.L1, t4.L2) as L1, 
       coalesce(t1.L2, t4.L2) as L2, 
       coalesce(t1.S, t4.S) as S,
       coalesce(t1.Q, t4.Q) as Q,
       coalesce(t1.Value, 0) as Value, 
       coalesce(t4.Prev_Value, 0) as Prev_Value
from (
  select L1, L2, S, Q, sum(value) as Value
  from table1
  group by L1, L2, S, Q
  ) as t1
left join
(
  select L1, L2, S, Q, sum(value) as Prev_Value
  from table1
  group by L1, L2, S, Q
) as t4 on
t1.L1 = t4.L1 and
t1.L2 = t4.L2 and
t1.Q = cast((cast(left(t4.Q,4) as numeric) +1) as varchar)+right(t4.Q,2) and
t1.S = t4.S
```

I got now result:
[image]

I know that into FY2015Q1 I don't have value C (for column S1).
But how to anyway display missing value?
[image]

Result of FULL OUTER JOIN:
[image]

Comment: I tried full join but I got to many rows then....

Comment: Does the row with Q column `FY2015Q1` and S column `C` exist in table1?

Comment: yes, value C exist only into FY15Q1

Comment: i think this is your problem: `t1.L1 = t4.[Sales Level 1] and
t1.L1 = t4.[Sales Level 2] and
t1.Q = cast((cast(left(t4.Q,4) as numeric) +1) as varchar)+right(t4.Q,2) and
t1.S = t4.S` => second line should be t1.L2 = .....  or maybe this is just part of your solution. change it anyways :)

Comment: it's typo, I had t1.L1=t2.L1 and t1.L2=t2.L2....

Comment: still not giving you the results you want? your code seems fine.....

Comment: The results of your full outer join also don't include a PrevValue for S1 = 'C'.   So why should it be included in your results?   Maybe your data isn't what you think it is.

Comment: If you include sample data in your question, it would be easier to help you.  Perhaps it's because I'm viewing this thread from a server, but all of your results are broken images for me.

Comment: sample of the data you have on 1st picutre, without column prev_value

Comment: Did you mis-speak in your comment above when you said that you DO have a row where value C exists in FY2015Q1?   It's not in the data in the first picture.   Did you mean that it only exists in FY2014Q1?

Comment: exaclty: row S1=C and Value=30, exist only into FY2014Q1, but I want to see the result into FY2015Q1 as prevValue

Comment: You should not be getting the results you say you are getting for the full outer join, if your data is what you say it is.   Can you add the Q column from t4 to your full outer join and post the result?   This would actually be much quicker to solve if you posted a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I added:  cast((cast(left(t4.Q,4) as numeric) +1) as varchar)+right(t4.Q,2) FiscalQuarter_Y => display ok, but for FY2016Q1 I have only value from prev year (it's ok, I will sort it out into tableau)

Comment: Yes, but do you have the C value for FY2014 in the t4.Q column?   And if so, what does it have for the other columns?

Comment: yes, I have the value, other columns have also values (FY2015Q1,C), only into col Value is 0.........and I did full join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a FULL OUTER JOIN, but include a WHERE clause that eliminates the rows from the t4 table that you don't want to see.

Comment: -> can you give me a example with WHERE?

Comment: I want to see all rows: if you make filter FY2015Q1, SUM of Prev_Value, should be equals SUM of Value for FY2014Q1

Comment: I can't see your data.  Please edit your question with examples of results of a full outer join, and which rows you want to filter out and why.

Comment: Tab result should be looks like on the second picture

Comment: I can't give an example unless you post the results of a full outer join.

Answer (score 0):

also change

```
t1.Q = cast((cast(left(t4.Q,4) as numeric) +1) as varchar)+right(t4.Q,2)
```

to

```
t1.Q = 'FY'+cast((cast(substring(t4.Q,3,6) as numeric) +1) as varchar)+right(t4.Q,2)
```